# Obsolete Report in salesforce due to relationships change from Lookup to Master Details

Tags: relationships, custom-report-type

I changed relationship from Lookup to Master Details. Now reports are obsolete.

There is no option to change Master Details to Lookup. Is there any option to get those reports back?

Other than creating them again?

Please guide.